# Not able to set threshold in facerec framework ( face recognition)

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am new to face recognition. I am trying to do face recognition with the help of bytefish facerec framework. It works fine but results are not very accurate. Therefore, I want to put threshold. As per suggested on his page (https://github.com/bytefish/facerec), I should be able to do it. However, explanation on page isnt very clear. So heres what I am doing.

My classifier

```
def predict(self, q):
        distances = []
        for xi in self.X:
            xi = xi.reshape(-1,1)
            d = self.dist_metric(xi, q)
            distances.append(d)
        if len(distances) > len(self.y):
            raise Exception("More distances than classes. Is your distance metric correct?")
        distances = np.asarray(distances)
        # Get the indices in an ascending sort order:
        idx = np.argsort(distances)
        # Sort the labels and distances accordingly:
        sorted_y = self.y[idx]
        sorted_distances = distances[idx]
        # Take only the k first items:
        sorted_y = sorted_y[0:self.k]
        sorted_distances = sorted_distances[0:self.k]
        # Make a histogram of them:
        hist = dict((key,val) for key, val in enumerate(np.bincount(sorted_y)) if val)
        # And get the bin with the maximum frequency:
        predicted_label = max(hist.iteritems(), key=op.itemgetter(1))[0]
        # A classifier should output a list with the label as first item and
        # generic data behind. The k-nearest neighbor classifier outputs the 
        # distance of the k first items. So imagine you have a 1-NN and you
        # want to perform a threshold against it, you should take the first
        # item 
        return [predicted_label, { 'labels' : sorted_y, 'distances' : sorted_distances }]
```

---

### My model

```
 def predict(self, X):
        q = self.feature.extract(X)
        return self.classifier.predict(q)
```

---

My server.py which generates the output

```
def get_prediction(image_data):
    image = preprocess_image(image_data)
    prediction = model.predict(image)
    predicted_label = prediction[0]
    classifier_output = prediction[1]
    distance = classifier_output['distances'][0]
    #distance = classifier.predict(self, q)
    #distance = 11
    if distance > 10.0:
        return "nonsense"
    else:
        print prediction
```

So the problem is I am not able to get the distance here. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while I was able to solve the problem. Threshold should be done in classifier file not in server.py.

### Solution

```
        distances = []
        for xi in self.X:
            xi = xi.reshape(-1,1)
            d = self.dist_metric(xi, q)
            distances.append(d)
        if len(distances) > len(self.y):
            raise Exception("More distances than classes. Is your distance metric correct?")
        distances = np.asarray(distances)
        # Get the indices in an ascending sort order:
        idx = np.argsort(distances)
        # Sort the labels and distances accordingly:
        sorted_y = self.y[idx]
        sorted_distances = distances[idx]
        # Take only the k first items:
        sorted_y = sorted_y[0:self.k]
        sorted_distances = sorted_distances[0:self.k]
        #sorted_distances = 1134.04873217
        # Make a histogram of them:
        hist = dict((key,val) for key, val in enumerate(np.bincount(sorted_y)) if val)
        # And get the bin with the maximum frequency:
        predicted_label = max(hist.iteritems(), key=op.itemgetter(1))[0]
            # A classifier should output a list with the label as first item and
            # generic data behind. The k-nearest neighbor classifier outputs the 
            #global unknown
        if sorted_distances > 1800 :
                return [predicted_label]
        else:
                return [predicted_label]
```